# Blue screen during Windows 10 installation using the Boot Camp Assistant

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp

I have been trying to instal Windows 10 on my late 2019 MacBook Pro 16", but I keep getting blue screens during the "Copying Windows files" which stays at 0% for a couple of minutes before the blue screen.

I have tried resetting the NVRAM and the SMC twice, and I even re-installed Monterey OS.

Nothing seems to work and I need windows but don't have any other computer.

Note: is that I had my MacBook Pro's logic board replaced twice as part of the warranty since the first time they replaced it it was with a faulty board. I am now way past the 90 days that you get after the warranty expires.

Edit : I was following these steps : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468

Comment: There are many details missing, the main question is: Bootcamp or VM? And further, what exact steps have you done and where exactly does this "Copying windows files" come up?

Comment: @X_841 : I said in the title that it was In Bootcamp. I was following apple's instructions : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468
Copying windows files comes up right after I choose the language, timezone, windows 10 version and accept window 10 policies. It is literally the first step and it won't get past 0%...